# pls help- have reinstalled lubuntu cosmic and flash will not install this time- i need the apt line for cannonical repository and cannot find it?

Tags: lubuntu, flash, repository

As stated, really-
 have reinstalled system and previously flash has been easy terminal install for this relative noob- but, now, the terminal approach fails and from reading others travails seems i need to add the canonical repository, but- i do not know the address for said repository.
(firefox on lubuntu cosmic, freshly installed and updated...)

Answer (score 0):

`flashplugin-installer` is in the `multiverse` repository.

([source of info](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=flashplugin-installer))

I do not know the method for doing this in 18.10 Lubuntu, but enable the `multiverse` repository and refresh the sources.

In stock Ubuntu the selection is here:

[image]

Comment: Ive got the multiverse tickbox on lubuntu- is very similar- but how do i make it refresh?

Comment: When you click close it should do it.

Comment: ok- now, it says in terminal flash is installed- and youtube works, but, when i go to the site i need- (ok, want, is flash game) it is still asking me to enable flash...
i think tea, smoke and new attack called for.